# Ubuntu crashes when booting form CD

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 11.10 on my PC. I first tried Wubi to see how it supports my hardware. It didn't boot at all and crashed. I tried to load Ubuntu from a CD, the same thing happened. I have windows 7 installed already.

-Graphic Care: NVIDIA GeForce GT 240

-CPU: Intel i5

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to boot liveCD of some other Linux distro: like Damn Small Linux and see if it works. This will help You to figure out if it is some kernel bug or something in Ubuntu.

Comment: 10.04 load up but 11.10 and 11.04 don't.

Comment: Well I think it might be a bug. In reality the latest versions of ubuntu are appearing as somewhat beta versions in my opinion. Releasing a new OS every six months seems for me like a little madness. I'd recommend using 10.04 or to wait for another LTS version and start using it after 3-4 months from its release